# setting up DNS and applying SSL certificate on sharepoint server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, ssl, windows-server

So i have installed SharePoint server in a multi shared minrole environment for our environment. Currently the SharePoint site url bears this format http:\\servername, however they want the more secured https:\\ protocol which will require them to get an SSL certificate. However SSL certificate cannot be issued to non-registered domains. Currently they already have an SSL certificate issued to *.9mobile.com.ng domain but after applying the certificate to a site in the SharePoint farm, i get below error

[image]

I need assistance to successfully apply SSL cert without errors. My initial thought is to setup DNS for SharePoint but i don't know how to go about this

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps to configure the SSL in SharePoint:

**Obtain a Certificate**

Get the authenticated certificate ready from the vendor.

**Import Certificate Into SharePoint Webserver**

- Copy your .pfx (. cer file) file to a location on the SharePoint Webserver.
- Open IIS manager and go to Server certificates.
- Select Import on the actions pane.
- Locate the .pfx(. cer file) you just copied to the server, supply the password, and check the box to allow the certificate to be exported.
- Click OK.

**Configure IIS Bindings**

After you have imported the certificate you will need to bind your site to use https. To configure the IIS bindings complete the following steps:

- Open IIS manager and go to your SharePoint site
- Right-click on the site and select Edit Bindings
- Select Add binding.
- From the drop-down choose HTTPS and select the certificate that you just added to the server.
- Fill in the Host header information and click OK.

**Configure SharePoint for SSL**

Now that you have added your certificate to IIS and bound it to the site, you’ll need to configure SharePoint to use SSL using Alternate Access Mappings. Alternate Access Mappings is how SharePoint determines how to handle the incoming URL requests and redirects to them the appropriate URL, in this case we are using HTTPS.

- Open Central Admin on SharePoint Server. Go to Application
  Management, then select Alternate Access Mappings.
- Select the web app that you want to change to SSL by selecting it from the top right drop-down menu.
- Edit the default public URL and change HTTP to HTTPS to redirect the site to use SSL.
- To redirect HTTP requests to be automatically redirected to HTTPS, click on Add an Internal URL.
- Add the non-HTTP URL and make sure the zone is set to default.
- Once you save your settings test your site by accessing the site in your browser.

For details refer to the below article:

[Configuring SSL on SharePoint Sites](https://petri.com/configure-ssl-sharepoint-sites)

[Configure SSL for SharePoint 2013/2016](https://www.google.com/amp/s/sharepointdiv.wordpress.com/2018/05/04/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013-2016/amp/)

Note:

- For friendlier URL, we need to add the DNS entry to the host file.

**How to update the host file in SharePoint?**

In your web server go to the path :

**C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC**

Copy the back of **hosts** file.

Then open the main **hosts** file in notepad.

At the end of the this file first add the server **ipconfig** port then the friendlier URL text. By default sample entries will be there in commented mode, you can refer that.

For details about host file update, refer to the below article:

[SharePoint | Host File Location](https://www.google.com/amp/s/myspquestions.wordpress.com/2019/04/04/sharepoint-host-file-location/amp/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. However i have already successfully installed the certificate and configured binding as you have directed. The problem is not about installing and configuring cert. This has already been done, however, the certificate throws an error that "the certificate is been issued to another site address". 9mobile,com.ng. But my current site address still carries https://<Servername>. What can i do to ensure the certificate doesn't keep flagging this error?

Comment: @kellboy22 The only two things you can do is either get a new cert that matches your existing server name or change your server’s name to match the cert you’ve provided it (such as site.9mobile.com.ng).